# How to append 5 (trials 1-5) groups of values (45 total) to 5 lists

Tags: python, pandas

I find it hard to believe this question hasn't been answered, but I failed to locate it.

My program analyzes an event by conducting 5 trials, each with slightly different inputs. The program works as intended, but I believe the list_to_DataFrame section is needlessly redundant.

Each list / variable contains the name of the trial it contains/belongs to (t1 / t2).

```
t1x = []
t2x = []

t1x.append(b1s)
t1x.append(b2s)
t1x.append(adj.b1r_t1)
t1x.append(b1w_t1)
t1x.append(adj.b2r_t1)
t1x.append(b2w_t1)
t1x.append(bcs_t1)
t1x.append(winloss_t1)
t1x.append(losswin_t1)

t2x.append(b1s)
t2x.append(b2s)
t2x.append(adj.b1r_t2)
t2x.append(b1w_t2)
t2x.append(adj.b2r_t2)
t2x.append(b2w_t2)
t2x.append(bcs_t2)
t2x.append(winloss_t2)
t2x.append(losswin_t2)
```

What strategy would most efficiently append these values to their corresponding lists?

Comment: If you're looking for a solution that merely takes less lines and typing, consider a for loop. 
```
for i in (b1s, b2s, adj.b1r, ...):
    t1x.append(i)
```

Comment: Can I post an answer that involves eval?

Comment: @AnnZen not sure what you mean by eval, but I'm always interested in learning new concepts.

Comment: Thank you @BrendenPrice. That solves a chunk of the problem. Any idea how I could make a for loop that also takes a (q) input. i.e. for i in (b1s, b2s, adj.b1r_t(q), adj.b1w_t(q), etc): tqx.append(i)

Comment: @AbovetheBook In this case would ```adj.b1rw_t(q)``` be a function call, taking q as a parameter? If that is the case, then if the function returns the value, then you can just append the function exactly like that.

I apologize if that's a dumb question, I'm not familiar with pandas, but I have used python a decent amount, so I'm attempting to answer without fully understanding the circumstances of the problem.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking @BrendenPrice. the values being appended are variables defined earlier on in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way using [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
t1x = []
t2x = []

for n in ['1','2']:
    for s in ['b1s','b2s',f'adj.b1r_t{n}',f'b1w_t{n}',f'adj.b2r_t{n}',f'b2w_t{n}',f'bcs_t{n}',f'winloss_t{n}',f'losswin_t{n}']:
        eval(f't{n}').append(eval(s))
```

Or, using [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

```
for n in ['1','2']:
    exec(f"t{n}x = [b1s,b2s,adj.b1r_t{n},b1w_t{n},adj.b2r_t{n},b2w_t{n},bcs_t{n},winloss_t{n},losswin_t{n}]")
```

Not recommended using eval and exec, read this [article](https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/) first!

Comment: Thank you very much @AnnZen. Cheers.

Comment: I just hope I don't get downvotes like the last time I used eval.

Comment: why would you get downvotes for using eval? @AnnZen

Comment: Because *eval is evil*, although it *is* a powerful tool. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi37fHI5ejpAhVhc98KHWYBBp0QFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1832940%2Fwhy-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice&usg=AOvVaw1PjVANKQ9uA2QrEHg65A8w